# insert a row in a table that links with PK autoincrement of another table

Tags: c#, database, schema

I have two tables

contact table

- contactID (PK auto increment)
- FirstName
- LastName
- Address

etc..

Patient table

- PatientID
- contactID (FK)

How can I add the contact info for Patient first, then link that contactID to Patient table
when the contactID is autoincrement (therefore not known until after the row is created)

I also have other tables
-Doctor, nurse etc
that also links to contact table..

Teacher table

- TeacherID
- contactID (FK)

So therefore all the contact details are located in one table.

Is this a good database design?

or is it better to put contact info for each entity in it's own table..

So like this..

Patient table

- PatientID (PK auto increment)
- FirstName
- LastName
- Address

Doctor table

- DoctorID (PK auto increment)
- FirstName
- LastName
- Address

In terms of programming, it is easier to just have one insert statement.
eg.
INSERT INTO Patient VALUES(Id, @Firstname,@lastname, @Address)

But I do like the contact table separated (since it normalize the data) but then it has issue with not knowing what the contactID is until after it is inserted, and also probably needing to do two insert statements (which I am not sure how to do)

=======

**Reply to EDIT 4**

With the login table, would you still have a userid(int PK) column?
E.g

Login table
UserId (int PK), Username, Password..

Username should be unique

Answer (score 0):

You must first create the Contact and then once you know its primary key then create the Patient and reference the contact with the PK you now know. Or if the FK in the Patient table is nullable you can create the Patient first with NULL as the ContactId, create the contact and then update the Patient but I wouldn't do it like this.

The idea of foreign key constraints is that the row being referenced MUST exist therefore the row being referenced must exist BEFORE the row referencing it.

If you really need to be able to have the same Contact for multiple Patients then I think it's good db design. If the relationship is actually one-to-one, then you don't need to separate them into two tables. Given your examples, it might be that what you need is a Person table where you can put all the common properties of Doctors, Teachers and Patients.

**EDIT:**
I think it's inheritance what you are really after. There are few styles of implementing inheritance in relational db but here's one example.

[Person database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7MPE.png)

PersonId in Nurse and Doctor are foreign keys referencing Person table but they are also the primary keys of those tables.

To insert a Nurse-row, you could do like this (SQL Server):

```
INSERT INTO Person(FirstName) VALUES('Test nurse')
GO
INSERT INTO Nurse(PersonId, IsRegistered) VALUES(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 1)
GO
```

**EDIT2:**
Google reveals that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` equivalent in mysql is `LAST_INSERT_ID()` [[mysql doc]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

**EDIT3:**
I wouldn't separate doctors and nurses into their own tables so that columns are duplicated. Doing a select without inner joins would probably be more efficient but performance shouldn't be the only criteria especially if the performance difference isn't that notable. There will many occasions when you just need the common person data so you don't always have to do the joins anyway. Having each person in the same table gives the possibility to look for a person in a single table. Having common properties in a single table also allows you have to have doctor who is also a patient without duplicating any data. Later, if you want to have more common attributes, you'd need to add them to each "derived" table too and I will assure you that one day you or someone else forgets to add the properties in one of the tables.

If for some reason you are still worried about performance and are willing to sacrifice normalization to gain performance, another possibility is to have all person columns in the same table and maybe have a type column there to distinguish them and just have a lot of null columns, so that all the nurse columns are null for doctors and so on. You can read about [inheritance implementation strategies](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) to get an idea of even though you aren't using Entity Framework.

**EDIT4:**
Even if you don't have any nurse-specific columns at the moment, I would still create a table for them if it's even slightly possible that there will be in the future. Doing an inner join is a pretty good way to find the nurses or you could do it in the WHERE-clause (there a probably a billion ways to do this). You could have type column in the Person table but that would prevent the same person being a doctor and a patient at the same time. Also in my opinion separate tables is more "strict" and more clear for (future) developers.

I would probably make PersonId nullable in the User table since you might have users that are not actual people in the organization. For example administrators or similar service users. Think about in terms of real world entities (forget about foreign keys and nullables), is every user absolutely part of the organization? But all this is up to you and the requirements of the software. Database design should begin with an entity relationship design where you figure out the real world relationships without considering how they will be mapped to a relational database. This helps you to figure out what the actual requirements are.

Comment: Each patient, doctor, nurse has their own unique contact address..

Isn't contact table similar to person table?

The reason why I normalize the contact to one table is to stop the patient, doctor, nurse essentially having the same columns...
Firstname, lastname, phoneno, address etc..


Can you show me how you would design it with a person table? 
And also the insert/select statement to reference that new contact to put as FK in the patient or doctor table etc..

Comment: Patient, doctor, nurse all have 1 to 1 relationship with contact table..
But they would have their own unique columns e.g doctor - speciality

Comment: I tested your query in mssql management studio and it works..

Do you think it is better to put one large person table and link with other tables like doctor, nurse etc..
Or have a doctor, nurse, patient with their own FirstName, LastName columns?

In terms of performance, is slower to do an inner join from two tables vs just select * from table?
Also applies to
-search
-insert
-update
-delete

In terms of queries it is a lot more complex to do 
CRUD operations.

Also is it bad to have only one personId link everything..
If I was to have doctor specialty table then it link to same personId

Comment: If I was to have a login table...linked to Person table..

Would you have the PersonId(FK) Nullable
 in the Users table?

Since you would need to login first, before you can create/edit your contact..

It would be a 1 to 1 relationship..

Only doctor and nurse would need to login, patients normally would not login (in future updates they might be able) instead it would be updated by someone else like the doctor etc.. 

Login table
 - UserId (int) PK
 - Username
 - Password
 - PersonId (FK) Nullable

Would you link UserID to Person table or PersonId to the Login table?

How would you design it?

Comment: Also with the nurse, currently there is no specific data required for a nurse  e.g. IsRegister

Should I still create nurse table with the only data, being PersonID (FK PK)

This is the only way to find the nurses in the Person table? ie inner join the two tables nurse and person and find the common PersonId.

Comment: I think you should add your questions to the original post so that the question-answer logic remains clear. Also I think this question is becoming quite bloated so if you have more questions about database design, I think you should considering asking another question.

Comment: Your help has been great to this thread. Thanks.

How do u suggest I add it to the original question?

I think the questions are all related to this question ie (this hospital system)..so I think it should stay together..
Else I would have to keep track of each question thread..